# Efficient positional query on small documents with Lucene

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene, indexing

I have a large dataset composed by billion of small documents (~200 char/doc).
What is the most efficient way to execute a positional query and get only the best three documents?

My idea is not to create a positional index and execute such a query on the whole dataset, but to build a positional index on the fly with the results of a simple boolean query and then execute the positional query to get the best three document that i need.

So, instead of:
billion of docs -> build a positinal index -> execute positional query -> get best three docs

I would like to do the following:
billion of docs -> build a normal index -> execute boolean query -> get the best 250 (high number) -> build with the result an in-ram positional index -> execute positional query -> get best three docs.

I think that by doing so i will reduce search time by paying a small approximation.
Is thare any other/better solution to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would try using a search filter.  Perhaps a [`TermsFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/queries/org/apache/lucene/queries/TermsFilter.html) might be adequate, but fairly certainly, a [`QueryWrapperFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/QueryWrapperFilter.html).  These can be wrapped with a [`CachingWrapperFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/CachingWrapperFilter.html), if it would be beneficial to cache the results of the filter.

When passed to your [`IndexSearcher.search`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Filter,%20int%29) call, this will restrict the query to searching those documents accepted by the filter.

Since you have included the [solr](/questions/tagged/solr) tag, filtered queries can be used in solr as well, using the [`fq` parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq).

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with femtoRgon. If the same terms occur in your positional queries you could also think about caching the (sub-)results of your positional queries.

Lets say you use SpanQuery objects you could introduce a CachingSpanQuery class by yourself which store the resulting Spans somehow. For efficiency you need a compressed way to store the position informations.